# PowerShell Resolving .NET Tab Completion Methods and Properties

Tags: .net, powershell, console

I can type this `[System.` on the PowerShell console and then use Tab completion, but is there a way to resolve all possible values after the `.`? I know that I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to *show* all the values, but can I programmatically return all values?

Similarly, I can type `[System.IO.Path]::` and Tab completion will show me Properties like `GetFileNameWithoutExtension` (and again, I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to show the values) but for this also, is there a way to programmatically return all possible .NET Methods and Properties?

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>CRTL</kbd>+<kbd>Spacebar</kbd> works with [System. as well...

As shown...

```
[System. # then CTRL+Spacebar

Loading personal and system profiles took 3487ms.
 [System.
Display all 241 possibilities? (y or n) _ 

# Select 'y'

 [System.
AccessViolationException               EventHandler                           OutOfMemoryException
Action<>                               Exception                              OverflowException
ActivationContext                      ExecutionEngineException               ParamArrayAttribute
Activator                              FieldAccessException                   PlatformID
AdjustmentRule                         FileStyleUriParser                     PlatformNotSupportedException...
```

If you mean, give you a popup list to select from,  like the ISE or VSCode or Visual Studio will, then no, and that is why the ISE / VSCode / Visual Studio and other PowerShell editors exist, to help of folks out who want to see the available goodness, before moving forward.

As for ...

> is there a way to programmatically return all possible .NET Methods
>   and Properties?

This just part of what I put together in my profile / my personal Module for lookups for such use cases as you seem to be after as well.

```
### Query Powershell Data Types
[AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() | 
Foreach-Object { $_.GetExportedTypes() }

# Or 

[psobject].Assembly.GetType(“System.Management.Automation.TypeAccelerators”)::get

# Or

    [psobject].Assembly.GetType("System.Management.Automation.TypeAccelerators")::Get.GetEnumerator() | 
Sort-Object -Property Key


# Finding the properties of a .NET class
[System.Environment].DeclaredProperties.Name


# Looping through static properties.
$obj = [environment]
$obj | get-member -Static -MemberType property | 
foreach name | 
foreach { "$_ = $($obj::$_)" }


<#
 Get any .NET types and their static methods from PowerShell. 
 Enumerate all that are currently loaded into your AppDomain.
#>  
[AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() | 
foreach { $_.GetTypes() } | 
foreach { $_.GetMethods() } | 
where { $_.IsStatic } | 
select DeclaringType, Name | 
Out-GridView -PassThru -Title '.NET types and their static methods'

# Instantiate the types using new-object and call instance methods. 
# You can use get-member on an instance to get the methods on a type.

$Object = [psobject].Assembly.GetType(“System.Management.Automation.TypeAccelerators”)::get
$Object | Get-Member
$Object | Get-Member -Static
$Object.GetType()
$Object.GetEnumerator()


# Show Public methods
[System.Management.Automation.ModuleIntrinsics]::GetModulePath

# Show Private methods
[System.Management.Automation.ModuleIntrinsics] | 
Get-Member -Static

### .Net API Browsers
<#
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?view=netframework-4.8
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/additional-apis/index
http://pinvoke.net
#>
```

In my profile / ModuleLibrary, I call these and more stuff I have there as needed directly and indirectly in my code.